# How To Prevent Alt Up Message From Reaching Browser Window In AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey, alt

How can I prevent the Alt key Up message from reaching the active window (a browser), which shows the previously hidden menu bar?

BTW, I'm snapping the window to the left side border with Alt + Mouse-Left-Button.

Normally, when not using this key combination the Alt key can work as usual (activating/bringing-up menus).

```
!LButton::
  Send {Click}
  Send #{Left}
  Send {Blind}{LAlt Up}  ->  Send {Esc}   ; Worked better for apps like Notepad2, not browser
  Return   ; Configured browser to not use Alt key to pop-up menu bar (can use F10, anyway)
```

EDIT: Added workaround and suggestion from user3419297

Comment: What you're asking should be possible via some complicated manipulation of the Windows messages, but I'm seriously skeptical that that's what you actually want. I'm also having trouble understand what your script is supposed to do. Rebinding `Alt` + `LButton` to `Win` + `←` I get, but why are you sending a click, and an `LAlt Up` in blind mode? I also don't get what you mean by "activating/bringing-up menus", you mean some hotkey functional the Alt key has in whatever program you're using? Can you explain better what exactly you're doing here, and what sort of results you're hoping to see?

Comment: The click activates the window under the mouse, any further Sends will act on that window. You can ignore the Blind part, trying to figure out if it could help based on examples online. If you try Alt+LButton on Firefox window, when all is done you get the activation of the hidden menu bar on Alt Up.

Comment: I should be able to use Alt key combinations without the app reacting to the Alt key press during the sequence, or afterwards.

Comment: Try replacing `Send {Blind}{LAlt Up}` with `Send {Alt Down}{Alt Up}` or `Send {Esc}`. You can also try adding `KeyWait, Alt` before it.

Comment: "KeyWait Alt" prevents using the hotkey more than once while holding the Alt key and sometimes it doesn't work. Since I configured the browser to not use the Alt key (and no longer an issue), "Send {Esc}" works better with simpler apps like Notepad2: pressing down the Alt key activates the menus, but when the keys are released the menus are no longer active. Thanks, user3419297.